# Find the probability mass function

Tags: probability

Let X be the number of times a basketball player scores in free throws. Suppose that
the probability that he scores at least once in six free throws is equal to 0.999936.

Find the probability mass function of X.

I'm a bit confused on how to solve this. I'm trying to solve it as a binomial experiment but, I'm not quite sure what 0.999936 represents or how many trials are being conducted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is still a binomial experiment, but you need to figure out the probability of making a free throw in one attempt.

Let $p$ be the probability that he makes a free throw (in one attempt).
Solving
$$0.999936=P(\text{at least one out of six free throws})=1-P(\text{misses all six})=1-(1-p)^6$$
gives $p=0.8$. From here, you see that $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(6,0.8)$, and you can write down the pmf explicitly if you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Our Knowledge**:  the *actual* probability of scoring at least once in six throws.
$$\mathsf P_{\!A}(X\geq 1) =\frac {999936}{10^6}$$
**Our model**: *If* $X$ has a binomial distribution with parameter $p$ *then* the *theoretical* probability is: $$\mathsf P_{\!T}(X=n) = (1-p)^{6-n} p^{n}$$

**Our Solution**: Use the Law of Complements and equate and determine $p$.
$$\mathsf P_{\!T}(X=0) = 1 - \mathsf P_{\!A}(X\geq 1)$$